# Why score is everytime is 1.0 in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

My json is below

- I have to match first from sports
- In that i need to extract search string
- The issue is i am getting score 1.0 for every document

```
[{'id':1, 'name': 'christiano ronaldo', 'description': 'football@football.com', 'type': 'football', 'var':'sports'},
{'id':2, 'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'messi@fifa.com','type': 'soccer','var':'sports'},
{'id':3, 'name': 'sachin', 'description': 'was', 'type': 'cricket', 'var':'sports'}]
```

My dsl query is below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "var.keyword": [
              "sports"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "sachin* OR messi",
          "fields": [
            "name^1024",
            "description^32"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My out

```
{'took': 911,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'newtestplayer',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '2',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': 2,
     'name': 'lionel messi',
     'description': 'messi@fifa.com',
     'type': 'soccer',
     'var': 'sports'}},
   {'_index': 'newtestplayer',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '3',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': 3,
     'name': 'sachin',
     'description': 'was',
     'type': 'cricket',
     'var': 'sports'}}]}}
```

You can see my score is `'_score':1.0` for every where. How to change that it will be according to `Fields` which i mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are using your query under the `filter context` which just filters the documents based on the search query, and don't compute the `score` of search queries.

Refer [query and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#relevance-scores) for more info,

In order to fix that, you need to use the query context, proper query should be like

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "var.keyword": [
                            "sports"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "sachin* OR messi",
                        "fields": [
                            "name^1024",
                            "description^32"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As it returns search results with proper scoring and executed in query context.

Comment: Even better is to put the terms query on `var.keyword` in the filter section as it brings nothing to scoring

Comment: @Val can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964121/how-to-add-suggestion-inside-term-query-in-dsl